# Audio file not playing

Tags: html, audio

I want to embed the audio file on the html page on the server. The audio file is in the same folder as the html file, the path in src in the tag audio is correct, why is it not playing?

html file

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<audio>
<source src="f.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: MIME type of MP3 files are not `audio/mp3` but `audio/mpeg`. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_source_type.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in mdn (https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio), the `<audio>` tag should be writted like
`<audio src="f.mp3" type="audio/mp3"></audio>`.

If you want to display your player, add `controls` to your tag.

If you want to play the media when the page load, you can add `autoplay`, but, many web browser not enable autoplay by default as you can read here https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/